Not able to use developer tools by default with Ubuntu 22.04 package `qt6-base-dev`
So currently, the package qt6-base-dev under Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't quite work.  All of the developer tools that are in /usr/bin are just symlinks to qtchooser, and apparently, as described here, qtchooser is more or less dead for good.  I tried to get it to work by writing the required config files, but qtchooser refuses to recognize /usr/lib/qt6/bin and /usr/lib/qt6/libexec simultaneously, which would be needed if I wanted to have access to moc and qmake at the same time.  This ain't gonna work.
Now, this is all sad and bad, but I was wondering if there was a somewhat agreed-upon "proper" solution to this.  Manually putting the bin and libexec dirs in your PATH, works, but that's kludgy and I can't help but think there's got to be a better way.
I'm just trying to set up a development environment to start writing a desktop app.  I didn't think it would be this annoying, especially considering that it's the official package from the Ubuntu maintainers.
